# Problem with updating UI with background thread

Tags: android, java-threads

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // a potentially time consuming task
            final Bitmap bitmap =
                    processBitMap("image.png");
            imageView.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I read this code in android developers site and they mentioned that **the background operation is done from a separate thread while the ImageView is always manipulated from the UI thread.** But i do not understand how. Can anyone explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undoubtedly, you should use different thread for heavy processes in java. But, Anything related to UI changes, initializations like Views, Animations should be done in UI(Main) Thread which is created with your application.

You could also do:

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               final Bitmap bitmap =
                    processBitMap("image.png");

               new Handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        }
                    });


}
```

Even if you do a background job in another thread, `Handler` guarantees, setting image is done in UI/Main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It is not just about image view.

Every app has its own special thread that runs UI objects such as View objects; this thread is called the UI thread. Only objects running on the UI thread have access to other objects on that thread. Because tasks that you run on a thread from a thread pool aren't running on your UI thread, they don't have access to UI objects. To move data from a background thread to the UI thread, use a Handler or coroutine that's running on the UI thread.

For example ,look at this code

```
 GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { //IN THE MAIN THREAD

                var x = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // in IO THREAD
                    wait() //BACKGROUND WORK
                    }          

            
       time.text = x //setting text to text view in main thread not IO or any
                     //other thread
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Background operation is done from a separate thread while the
> ImageView is always manipulated from the UI thread.

All the UI elements in the `Android` app is working in the `Main thread` normally says `UI Thread`. If you are trying to do the long-running operation under the main thread it will freeze or Application not running exception will get. So you should do the network or database operation under the background thread and updating the UI elements such as ImageView in `UI Thread`.

**UI Thread** :

- When an application is started, Ui Thread is created automatically
- It is in charge of dispatching the events to the appropriate widgets
  and this includes drawing events.
- It is also the thread you interact with Android widgets with

**Runnable:**
Represents a command that can be executed. Often used to run code in a different Thread.

**Background operation**

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // here the background operation happening
        }
    }).start();
```

**`View.post(Runnable)` for accessing the UI thread from the background thread.**

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in most cases all views are manipulated or processed in the UI or main thread, another thread a.k.a. "background thread " is used for long operations such as network access or database, in order to avoid blocking of the main thread from UI events, where user will get the feeling that the App is crashing because screen will stop moving.

read more in the below documentation:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads

Answer (score -2):

You need to update your UI from main thread. To do that you use the code snippet below..

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // update UI elements here
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't just copy paste a code block, add a bit of explanation to your answer.